# Python MySQL Syntax Error - DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: python, mysql

I have the following MySQL + Python code:

```
data = json.loads(decoded_response)

insert_values = []
cursor = cnx.cursor()
add_data = """INSERT INTO pb_ya_camps (camp_id,camp_name) VALUES (%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE VALUES (%s,%s)"""

for jsonData in data["data"]:
        if "No" in jsonData["StatusArchive"]:
                print("...processing campaign ",jsonData["Name"],"into the database.")
                insert_values.append((jsonData["CampaignID"],jsonData["Name"]))

try:
        cursor.executemany(add_data,(insert_values,insert_values))
```

Which at the moment produces the following error:

```
MYSQL ERROR: Failed processing format-parameters; 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_tuple_to_mysql'
```

As far as I understand it is not liking the following:

```
cursor.executemany(add_data,(insert_values,insert_values))
```

I believe you can't do that with Python...but my problem probably derives from improper MySQL syntax. Could you please take a look at it?

```
INSERT INTO pb_ya_camps (camp_id,camp_name) VALUES (%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE VALUES (%s,%s)
```

I am not sure how to properly use the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE without having to re-specify all the values...   <<<--- **that is the main problem.**

I have read the following: [LINK TO PREVIOUS EXAMPLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867166/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update) however I don't want to rely on KEY UPDATE col1 = VALUES(col1) because in a further part of my script I have too many columns to keep listing as part of col = value for each column...

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `(insert_values,insert_values))`, try `insert_values * 2`.

Comment: [MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_tuple_to_mysql' exception with mysql-connector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910023/mysqlconverter-object-has-no-attribute-tuple-to-mysql-exception-with-mysql-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following MySQL Reference Manual, MySQL syntax for `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is:

```
INSERT INTO table (`a`, `b`, `c`) 
VALUES (1, 2, 3)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `c` = `c` + 1;
```

So in your case (please note that writing either `camp_id = %s` or `camp_id = VALUES(%s)` is the same:

```
INSERT INTO `pb_ya_camps` (`camp_id`, `camp_name`) 
VALUES (%s,%s) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `camp_id` = VALUES(%s), `camp_name` = VALUES(%s)
```

More information about the syntax at the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: Thanks GregD! so for every column I want to update I would I have specify: "column_name = value"?