# Python 'int64' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Tags: mysql

I have the following Python script to insert a csv file into a MySQL database:

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd

connection = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="localhost",
      user="xxxx",
      passwd="password",
      database="z_realestate"
      )

print("Now in For Sales Table: ")

forsale = pd.read_csv('for_sale.csv',encoding = "utf-8")
address = forsale.iloc[:,0]
state = forsale.iloc[:, 1]
city = forsale.iloc[:, 2]
zipcode = forsale.iloc[:, 3]
price = forsale.iloc[:, 4]
listingdate = forsale.iloc[:, 5]
bed = forsale.iloc[:, 6]
bath = forsale.iloc[:, 7]
sqft = forsale.iloc[:, 8]
url = forsale.iloc[:, 9]

for i in range(0,len(address)):
    cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=True)

    sql_select_query = """select * from `z_for_sale` where url = %s"""
    cursor.execute(sql_select_query, (url[i], ))

    if cursor.rowcount > 0:
        print(url[i])
        print('Already Exist')
    else:
        print('Inserting')
        sql_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO `z_for_sale`
                (`address`,  `state`,`city`,`zipcode`,`price`,`listing_date`,`bed`,`bath`,`sqft`,`url`)     VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%d,%s,%f,%f,%d,%s)"""

    insert_tuple = (address[i], state[i], city[i], zipcode[i],price[i],listingdate[i],bed[i],bath[i],sqft[i],url[i])

    result  = cursor.execute(sql_insert_query, (insert_tuple),)
    connection.commit()
```

---

When running the script, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

AttributeError: 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute     '_int64_to_mysql'

TypeError: Python 'int64' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

"Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-    parameters; Python 'int64' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

How do I fix this?  I have been trying to figure it out.  I have tried changing the field type in the table.  I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: If URL is unique and there is a primary or unique key on that column, [LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE IGNORE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) would be a way to quickly load these entries.

Comment: @danblack, how did you know that URL is a primary or unique key?

Comment: I don't, you're treating it as unique however. `SHOW CREATE TABLE z_for_sale`. You question's answer is probably similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910023/mysqlconverter-object-has-no-attribute-tuple-to-mysql-exception-with-mysql-c)

Comment: I changed the line to the format that is similar to the post you mentioned. Now the line result = cursor.execute(sql_insert_query, (insert_tuple),) needs to be changed, I assume.