# What is the correct syntax for ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert, auto-increment, on-duplicate-key

I   am trying to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in PHP. I   really am not sure what the correct syntax is. I   am using MySQL 8.0.19

I   have,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cart (title, price, productID, quantity) VALUES ('$title', '$price', '$productID', '$quantity') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity WHERE productID='$productID'";
```

And quantity is auto-increment and productID is the unique key. I   want quantity to increase if the productID already exists.

I   get the error,

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE productID='1'' at line 1".

Comment: [The manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) is a good start.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: I see `insert into where` construct attempts now and then but I've never figured out what the intention is :-?

Comment: Sort of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867166/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update with prepared statements.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I  am just creating this for a class at my university! I    would love to understand sql more but I   am not quite there yet.

Comment: Oh... There's even a popular question about it: [MySQL Insert Where query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a where clause because it updated based on the duplicate key and you have to assign the same value incremented by `$quantity`.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
  INSERT INTO cart (title, price, productID, quantity)
  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = quantity + ?;
");
$stmt->bind_param($title, $price, $productID, $quantity, $quantity);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: You'd probably want to increase it by `$quantity`, not `1`. Also, use prepared statements and don't quote numerics.

Comment: @Sammitch yes, I agree on both points. I was just trying to illustrate the correct usage of the INSERT/ON DUPLICATE